# Как сделать так,чтобы ссылка при наведении не двигала соседнюю ссылку?

Tags: html, css

Нужно, чтобы при наведении на какую-либо ссылку она не сдвигала ссылку по соседству.

```
<nav class="nav">
  <ul class="nav-list">
    <li><a href="#!">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#!">Updates</a></li>
    <li><a href="#!">Services</a></li>
    <li><a href="#!">Features</a></li>
    <li><a href="#!">About Us</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

```
.nav-list{
    display: flex;
    column-gap: 30px;
}
.nav-list li {
    display: inline-block;
}

.nav-list a{
    color: #000;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 600;
    
}

.nav-list a:hover{
    color: #2851E3;
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все что вам нужно это свойство `transform` и функция трансформации `scale`.

Так же вы назначили для `.nav-list` тип отображения `flex`, но совсем не пользуетесь этим. Чтобы дочерние элементы в `.nav-list` были в строку, что нужно применить свойство `flex-direction: row`.

```css
.nav-list {
  display: flex;
  column-gap: 30px;
  flex-direction: row;
}
.nav-list li {
  display: flex;
}
.nav-list > li a {
    color: #000;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 600;
}
.nav-list li > a:hover{
    color: #2851E3;
}
.nav-list > li:hover {
   transform: scale(1.3);
}
```

```html
<nav class="nav">
  <ul class="nav-list">
    <li><a href="#!">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#!">Updates</a></li>
    <li><a href="#!">Services</a></li>
    <li><a href="#!">Features</a></li>
    <li><a href="#!">About Us</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

- Про [transform и его функции](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/transform)
- Про [scale()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/scale)
- Про [flex-direction](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/flex-direction)